# Vector operation that would result in unique vector outcomes by preserving the order of appearance of the input vectors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, vectors

What could be a (good) mathematical operation/function that would take a certain number of $n$-dim vectors and always outputs a unique $m$-dim vector, the uniqueness of which also depends up on the order in which the input vectors appear. Here, its recommended that $n$ is equal to $m$, but could be different as well.

Example operations:

Suppose I have vectors $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ with same dimensions such that,

- $f(f(f(a, b), c), d) = h$
- $f(f(f(a, c), d), b) = g$
- $f(f(f(a, d), b), c) = j$
- All outputs which are unique (in terms of magnitude and direction), in our case $g$, $h$ and $j$ should have the same dimension regardless of number of inputs

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want $f$ to be *injective*? For that we can fix an embedding $\varphi:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ (even such a bijection exists, assuming the axiom of choice), then define $f$ to act as $\varphi$ coordinatewise.

Comment: @Berci I have a very minimal math background and so I do not understand a lot of math concepts. I looked up injective functions in wikipedia and understand what you mean and yes I suppose that is what I want.